# How can I add an Image type to an EF4 Code First Entity?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, ef4-code-only

How can I add an Image type to an EF4 Code First Entity? I need to add a column for thumbnail images.

```
public Image Thumbnail { get; set; }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Images are represented as binary in EF 4

http://thedatafarm.com/blog/data-access/sql-server-2008-data-types-and-entity-framework-4/

You will need to do something like this

```
public Binary Thumbnail {get; set}
```

Then convert the image to binary

This reference will help you with the image to binary conversion http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/6150-Convert-Image-binary-format.aspx

Answer (score 2):

```
public System.Data.Linq.Binary Thumbnail {get; set}
```

For those wondering where the type `Binary` is located, also i belive you can use `byte[]`