# BLOBs with Entity Framework 4 and SQL Compact 4

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, sql-server-ce

I asked this question earlier, but I failed to specify that I am working with SQL Compact 4, using Entity Framework 4 model-first development.

I am creating an EDM entity to represent a document, and the body of the document will be a WPF flow document of about 100K or so. I'd like to create the `Body` property for the document as a `binary`, but that data type has an 8K maximum. So, the best data type appears to be `image`.

Here's my question: What EF4 entity property type do I use to map to image? Does EF4 map to an `image` type automatically, or do I have to modify the mappings? Thanks for your help.

Comment: There is a good explaination of this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4156424/how-can-i-add-an-image-type-to-an-ef4-code-first-entity